# Checking for identical hashtable values

Tags: powershell, hashtable

How do I loop through a hashtable to verify that all the values are the same?

I have a script that returns a hashtable from an active-directory query. The value returned from each server should be the same so I want to return true if all values are the same or false if any values do not match the others. Ideally this would work even if a 4th or 5th server gets added without needing to update the script.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
server1                        0
server2                        0
server3                        0
```

Comment: What's the script you have so far?

Comment: `Function checkAccountReplication ($user, $property) {
 $servers = "server1", "server2", "server3"
 $results = @{}
 $servers | Foreach-Object {$results.($_) = (get-aduser $user -server $_ -property $property | select -ExpandProperty $property)}
 $results | ft
 
 
 
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most effective way but a very simple is the `@($h.Values | Group-Object).Count -eq 1`.

Example:

```
# all the same
$h = @{ server1=0; server2=0; server3=0 }

# gets True
@($h.Values | Group-Object).Count -eq 1

# different
$h = @{ server1=0; server2=0; server3=1 }

# gets False
@($h.Values | Group-Object).Count -eq 1
```

The special case is how to treat a table with 0 items. E.g. if it means all the same then `-le 1` can be used in the check.

Comment: The value returned could be a string or int. This would only work with  integers right?

Comment: It will work for any data types. But the way `Group-Object` treats your values as equal might or might not be what you want. You should try your potential edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a hash, pipe the hash variable's **.Keys** property to a **Foreach-Object** loop:

```
$MyHash.Keys | %{
  [...code...]
}
```

Within the loop, **$_** is set to each key name. To access a value within the loop, use `$MyHash.$_`, so for example you can test `if ($MyHash.$_ -ne $SomeVariable) { [...do something...]}`

That's how to loop through a hash. I'll leave it to you to use whatever logic you prefer to determine whether the values are all the same. If you run into a problem doing that, please post the code and explain what's not working about it.

**Caveat:** If you try to add or remove hash elements while looping over the hash you're modifying, you'll get an error. It doesn't apply in this particular case, but it's something to be aware of regarding looping through hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Compare-Object $ServerList1 $ServerList2` ?